# Rust lang and Cheaters

Tags: anti-cheat, rust

So I started to learn Rust for personal usage, i am Back-end Node.js dev originally.

And I see that people often say Rust is a very secure solution because of memory management. In theory games/engines written in Rust could be a problem to cheaters?

I don't have a big knowledge of how people make cheats for games. I just guessing that it might be because somehow you can change Heap or something like that.

I have a few ideas for my first future game and want to make it secure without doing it fully server-side.

Comment: If people can make changes to your backend side of the code, you have a different problem. And any code that can run in the frontend can be manipulated with enough dedication of a cheater

Comment: @Zibelas haha, a very nice analogy with front-end. Yeah if it's on the front-end you can do whatever you desire and you will have to validate data from FE on BE. Makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When people claim "Rust is secure", then what they mean is that Rust makes it very difficult for developers to create bugs which could result in security vulnerabilities like buffer overflows or use-after-free. Those are the kind of vulnerabilities which can be exploited by attackers who send  malicious files or network messages in order to attack the systems of other people.

But those aren't the vulnerabilities cheaters use. They are attacking *their own* system, so they have no need for exploits like that.

Cheaters use techniques like:

- Patching the game executable
- Injecting code into the game executable by replacing DLL files
- Replacing assets
- Reading and changing process memory
- Simulating inputs

Rust does nothing which makes any of that any easier or harder to do.

One argument you *could* make is that Rust is relatively new, so the tools to reverse-engineer applications written in Rust are less mature than for languages like, say, C++ or C#. But that's a security-by-obscurity argument which can easily change when people start building those tools.

So tl;dr: No, using Rust does not prevent any cheating.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining cheaters' techniques!

So basically a common reason to use Rust is that you will have a more optimized game because of less chance to create some memory leaks/bugs and it runs a bit faster. Fibonacci is twice faster as know 

Comment: The answer does not claim a performance improvement. It's not clear that Rust's language-level features would have an impact on the performance of typical game workloads.

Comment: I am certainly not going to get involved in any "which programming language is the best" debates.